# Typescript on VSCode - Declaring a property on the window object

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

We embed Typescript projects (React) into our webpages. In some cases we need too allow our Typescript code to communicate with other elements on the page.

For example, we'd like a link to open a React-Typescript component, or vis versa, for a button in a React component, to open a jquery based modal.

For these purposes we created an object on the window object.

```
window.gwFunctions = {
   openModal: ()=>{
      codeToOpenModal
   }
}
```

VSCode complains when it sees `window.gwFunctions`

```
Property 'TS_FUNCTIONS' does not exist on type 'Window'.ts(2339)
```

It suggests as a possible fix to `declare property gwFunctions`. Choosing this option will solve the problem by declaring this property on the window interface in `lib.dom.d.ts`. The only problem is that this file is located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts` which is shared by all projects/workspaces.

Is it possible to declare this property only on the current project/workspace?

Comment: Why not use `window['gwFunctions'] = ...` and access the same way `var bla = window['gwFunctions'];`?

Comment: jep this sounds correct @Silvermind .. if you define something global its global, like localstorage. if you want to handle restrictions, you have to create an object which holds all data, and then you need functions which handles the data and the access.
i.e. :
window.sharedData = {
namespace: 'mynamespace',
values: []
}

now you can write some accessors who handle the restriction

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the Window type definition by placing this in your TypeScript file.

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        gwFunctions: {
            [key: string]: () => void;
        }
    }
}
```

The type declaration in the lib.dom.d.ts file will merge with the one that you define. [Here is the official documentation on declaration merging in the TypeScript handbook.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)